# Having problem with installing npm in ubuntu 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, apt, software-installation, npm

After installing node.js I execute this command:

```
sudo apt-get install npm
```

And getting error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade -f npm node-gyp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  nodejs-dev : Depends: libssl-dev (>= 1.0.0g) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: npm comes bundled together with an install of nodejs ... never a need to do a separate npm install

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get upgrade -f npm node-gyp`? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I added output of the command  in Question, please see

Comment: Thank. Let's go further! What's the output of `sudo apt-get upgrade -f libssl-dev`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster issue is solved, I put my solution as an answer in this thread. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

After facing numerous errors, finally get success to resolve the issues. Here are the steps I followed.

First I installed "curl" by following http://sourcedigit.com/20782-install-curl-ubuntu-via-command-line/ . This article provides two ways to install curl and I successfully installed curl using **"Alternate Method To Install Curl"**.

Then I executed commands in sequence

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

By executing above nodejs command, node js version 8 is installed with npm version 5.3.0

Answer (score 1):

add python libraries for that:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

add the ppa for latest nodejs with this command :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
```

then try :

```
sudo apt install -y nodejs
```

I hope this will work for you, because this works for me.

Comment: nodejs already installed in my system, however i am facing issue with npm

Comment: it will install nodejs and npm... did you try it??

Comment: first command is successfully executed but on second command getting curl  error program is not found. but when i tried to install curl again get dependency error "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.47.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.2 is to be installed"

Comment: issue     sudo apt-get install build-essential  curl       then re-do above steps in this answer

Comment: you can install curl using this tutorial http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-curl-ubuntu-16-04/